# Programming Language Editor Python

Tags: python, editor

I've been trying

```py
with open('C:Users/Kings/Downloads/editor.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.readlines(1)
    f.seek(0)
    if text[:6] == "print ":
        print(text[7:])
```

to get the editor.txt file and read the first line. I want it to read the keyword print then print everything after it. So for instance if it reads

```
print Hello, world!
```

in the text document it will print Hello, world! in my Python editor. I have the editor.txt in my downloads but I don't know what's wrong. I'm very new to open() by the way.

Comment: You also forgot a `/`, I believe, after `C:`

Comment: I added the slash and it had no difference. I just use f.seek because I'm weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open(inp_path, 'r') as f:
    text = f.readlines(1)
    f.seek(0)
    print(text[0][:6])
    if text[0][:6] == "print ":
        print(text[0][6:])
```

Please note that `text` is a list so you must first access it's first item. Alse, not that when using the `[a:b]` notation, `a` is included yet `b` is excluded.